# How do I find out whether enabling gcServer config is taking effect?

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection

I'm supporting a ASP.NET v2.0 app installed on a Windows 2003 SP3 Enterprise on a quad core 8G machine running on .NET 2.0 SP1.

1. before enabling the config, ran "tasklist /m mscorwks.dll" 
   Image Name                     PID Modules
   w3wp.exe                      7888 mscorwks.dll
2. add  under  section in web.config
3. ran IISRESET, rebooted server too
4. ran "tasklist /m mscorsvr.dll"
   INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
5. ran "tasklist /m mscorwks.dll" 
   Image Name                     PID Modules 
   w3wp.exe                      6251 mscorwks.dll

It seems like gcServer is not taking effect. Are there any additional settings/ configurations necessary to get it working?

Comment: Add somewhere in your application a call to [`GCSettings.IsServerGC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.isservergc.aspx) to find out whether this setting took effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Sorry, just saw that the link below, and thus maybe the whole information, applies to IIS 6.0.  I don't know whether that is applicable to your environment.

I don't believe you can configure any GC setting on a per AppDomain basis, which is essentially what would happen when you only set it in a web.config file, thus on a per application basis.

You need to set this in the aspnet.config file. The Aspnet.config file is in the same directory as the Aspnet_isapi.dll file (check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx) for more information).

Edit: To figure out the GC in use, you can use [WinDBG/SOS and the eeversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb190764.aspx) command:

```
0:010> !eeversion
2.0.50727.3082 retail
Workstation mode
SOS Version: 2.0.50727.3053 retail build
```

Comment: Well, this is standard Win2K3 SP3. I just verified IIS version is 6
I just tried aspnet.config under C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727. still the tasklist /m mscorsvr.dll returns INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria

Answer (score 1):

See [this MSDN link, where Chapter 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998547.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic9) had the answer. Quote from Chapter 5:

> Note:   At the time of this writing, the .NET Framework 2.0 (code-named "Whidbey") includes both GCs inside Mscorwks.dll, and Mscorsvr.dll no longer exists.

I guess there is no way to check whether the server GC is working. EDIT: but see [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423158/111575).

Comment: @G33kKahuna: Rather than posting this as a new "answer", it should have been a comment to the answer provided by @Christian.K.

Comment: Yup, that is correct - I forgot :-(. See my orignal answer for a possibility to figure out which GC is being used.

Answer (score 1):

From code you can use `GCSettings.IsServerGC`.